# ForEach step on Gremlin

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a neo4j query like:

```
        ...
        "WITH DISTINCT k " +
        // classic for each loop for the new rankings information
        "FOREACH (app in $apps | " +
        // upsert the app
        " MERGE (a:App{appId:app.appId}) " +
        ...
        // end of loop
        ") " +
```

I'm using gremlin-java. In here, I want to give `$apps` as custom parameter. I've just checked gremlin document but I couldn't find a foreach step. Is there a suggestion?

```
graph.foreach(apps: map)...
```

**Solved with:**

```
...constant($apps).unfold().as(app)...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted you can use a `constant` step to inject a value into a query. However you can also use the `inject` step to insert a collection of values in a similar way. Here are a couple of simple examples - you can extend these patterns to include id, label and multiple property values as needed.

```
gremlin> g.inject([[id:1],[id:2],[id:3],[id:4]]).
           unfold().as('a').
           addV('test').
             property('SpecialId',select('a').select('id'))
==>v[61367]
==>v[61369]
==>v[61371]
==>v[61373]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('test').valueMap(true)
==>[id:61367,label:test,SpecialId:[1]]
==>[id:61369,label:test,SpecialId:[2]]
==>[id:61371,label:test,SpecialId:[3]]
==>[id:61373,label:test,SpecialId:[4]]



gremlin> g.inject(1,2,3,4).as('a').
           addV('test2').
             property('SpecialId',select('a'))
==>v[61375]
==>v[61377]
==>v[61379]
==>v[61381]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('test2').valueMap(true)
==>[id:61375,label:test2,SpecialId:[1]]
==>[id:61377,label:test2,SpecialId:[2]]
==>[id:61379,label:test2,SpecialId:[3]]
==>[id:61381,label:test2,SpecialId:[4]]
gremlin>
```

The first query injects a list of maps. The second a simple list. This is a bit like the `UNWIND` pattern you may be used to in Cypher and it works in a similar way.